# Simple Matrix Calculation

Tags: matrices

I am new to Math, and my knowledge is not good.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Show that $(M^*)^* = M$, $(M^T)^T = M$, and $(M^t)^t = M$.
I think I got some idea on the last 2, but the I am stuck at the first one.

Comment: What is $M^t$?  What is $M^T?$  What is $M^\ast$?

Comment: * is Complex Conjugate
T is Transpose
t is dagger

Comment: And what _is_ your idea?

Comment: @Sopheak You probably mean conjugate transpose. This should be useful: $z = a+bi$ is a complex number, then the complex conjugate of the complex conjugate of $z$ is $z$ itself.

Comment: Thank you. But I think I am dealing with Complex Conjugate of Matrix.

Comment: And because of that, I quite stuck with it.

Comment: Dagger? Do you mean conjugate transpose?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: I don't know how to type my idea in comment section. Sorry.

Comment: @Sopheak One key at a time!

Comment: Dagger is Hermitian Conjugate

Comment: Let the entry in row $i$, column $j$ be $a_{ij}$. Then work out the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of $(M^*)^*$ and the others.

Comment: If $A^\ast$ is just $A$ with each entry conjugated, then won't $(A^\ast)^\ast$ just be $A$ with each entry conjugated twice?

Comment: Yes! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of the kind of thinking you need:  Let $A^T$ be the transpose of the matrix $A$.  That is, you get $A^T$ from $A$ by switching rows and columns: Take the first row of $A$, write it down as a column (the first one) . Then take the second row of $A$, and write it down as a column, to the right of the first column you wrote down. Continue that way. When finnished in that way with all the rows, what you have written down is the transpose of $A$.

Now repeat the same procedure: Take the first row of $A^T$, write it down as a column. Continue with second row, ...

When terminated, what you have should be identical to the matrix $A$ with which you started.  You have shown that $(A^T)^T = A$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That helps me alots.